# React native: I can run the application on iOS simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I changed my computer recently, so I just downloaded my github repo again. When I decided to run the app on my device I got the red screen telling me No bundle URL present.

Once (a long time ago) I could not run the project, so I first run it on the simulator and then on the device and it worked. But now this is not working. The simulator works fine, but I can't run anything on the device. When I open xcode I see the main.jsbundle in red. I don't know if this is the problem.
Also my device is in the same network of my computer.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below steps:

Step 1: Open command prompt and run below command from project's root location.

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

Step 2: Add below line into `AppDelegate.m` file's `didlaunching` method

```
 jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
//jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@”index” fallbackResource:nil];
```

Comment: Hey,the first step really help. With that one I was able run the app. Could you explain me what exactly it does?. Then to enable the js debbug I had to start by myself the builder instead of letting xcode open it automatically,

Comment: @JacoboTapia if my answer is realy help to you then upvote or accept it so other can get help from it.

Comment: @JacoboTapia first step is only generate main.jsbundle file that missing in your project's bundle, and main.jsbundle file is required for run app into real device.

Comment: The first step helped me as well! I actually had a different error that kept telling me it `ld: library not found for ...` - but I had the same issue that it was working in simulator, just not a device. Why is this needed?